# Macbook Pro putting out low sound input

Tags: audio, speakers

Every app that I use, the speakers hardly put out sound even when set to full volume full blast. I went into sound settings and made sure the volume was up all the way and it sounds like it is on a mid-low volume.

It is a 2018 15" Macbook Pro running OS Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure any volume controls in the app you’re using aren’t turned all the way down. Also, try playing a different audio file, CD, or DVD, or try playing the file or disc on another computer or media player to isolate the problem. Check this thread https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-you-cant-hear-sound-from-your-speakers-mchlp1439/mac